# Consulta SQL retornando uma das colunas vazia, diferente da base de dados

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Estou fazendo uma consulta SQL, em banco Oracle, porém um dos campos retorna o valor vazio, diferente do que consta na tabela da base de dados.

Já tentei criar, e reconstruir os índices, porém o problema persiste.

O campo em si, é referente a um `left join` que faço na tabela.
Quando eu coloco apenas o campo no `select`, o valor retorna, porém eu preciso de mais campos no `select`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT
A.CAMPO1,
A.CAMPO2,
B.CAMPO3 -- CAMPO RETORNANDO VAZIO

FROM TABELAA A

LEFT JOIN TABELAB B 
ON A.CAMPO1 = B.CAMPO.1
```

Comment: Oi, você pode detalhar melhor, por favor? O que eu entendi: O campo campo3 da tabela B está retornando vazio quando usado     Left Join. Se é somente isso, campo campo1 da tabela A é igual ao campo campo1 da tabela B?

Comment: Raphael, tente reproduzir os mesmos dados aqui no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), se o problema persistir altere a sua pergunta e coloque o link do fiddle.

Comment: Você está utilizando LEFT JOIN. Isto significa que se CAMPO1 existir na TABELAA mas não na TABELAB então todos os campos da TABELAB retornarão NULL. É o que espera do LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Coloque a estrutura das tabelas e alguns dados para dar para entender melhor. Se ele está trazendo valor nulo é porque ele está nulo na tabela, o LEFT JOIN faz exatamente isso...se você não quer que ele traga os campos que não estão nulos use o INNER JOIN que ele vai trazer os registros que possuam valores nos campos que você está selecionando no seu seu SELECT

Answer (score -1):

Boa Tarde, tudo bem?

Tente executar desta forma:

```
SELECT
A.CAMPO1,
A.CAMPO2,
B.CAMPO3 -- CAMPO RETORNANDO VAZIO

FROM TABELAA A,
     TABELAB B 
WHERE   A.CAMPO1 = B.CAMPO1(+)
```

Eu tive o mesmo problema quando sai do SQL Server para o Oracle, justamente por conta de como o Oracle lida com o LEFT JOIN.

Att,